# PHP interprets string "cash" as zero

Tags: php

This is crazy. I ran across this in an app I was writing. The following code will echo "YES":

```
<?php
$var = 0;
if ($var == 'cash') echo 'YES';
else echo 'WEIRD';
?>
```

WHY??? How is zero interpretted to be equal to 'cash' ???

Comment: is $var supposed to be a string value or a number?

Comment: This is one of the most fundamental behaviors of PHP and is mentioned in countless questions. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for the relevant documentation, and use `===` if you want to see what you expect to see.

Comment: +1 @MarcB - to extend, the specific reason for this specific problem is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare a number and a string, the string is converted to number. When you convert string 'cash' to number, the result is zero. You can use strict comparison (===), so you compare not only the value, but the type as well, and no [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) will be involved

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare an integer to a string.

I would use the [===](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator for strict comparison